# DB client shows only date without time component..how can I convert?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am saving date with time into DB and using SQL Developer which by default shows just date. I know its matter of client config but I have seen query in Oracle that returned time component of date when one was present. Something like convert (HH:MM:SS). I am just interested in this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the time element of all dates as a one-off exercise use this DDL statement.

```
ALTER SESSION set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
/
```

or whatever date mask takes your fancy.

To set this permanently in SQL Developer, set parameters in

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS Parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

I you understand that it's a matter of client config and want to see time portion of date for some special purpose you can query it converting to char like this:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

More info on date format can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) or in [official docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)